# Drupal 7 - Registration pop up for new guest users

Tags: drupal

I own a drupal 7 site.

I have users that are coming to many pages of my site (not only home page) from different sources on the internet.

My goal is that when a guest user is entering the site, no matter which page, he will get nice popup that will offer him to register to the site. On the popup, I will write short text explaining the benefits of the site, even put a video (if possible).

I saw that in many sites, I get a popup message on top on the site (the rest of the site becomes dark) that offer me to register. I want to do something similar.

Can someone help me achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Popup On Load](https://drupal.org/project/popup_onload) module for displaying a pop up for guest visitors in a Drupal 7 site.